# dynamic memory allocation teaching materials?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

Besides the (somewhat dated) papers that appear in Wikipedia's ref section, are there good (teaching) materials that you know of that comprehensively discuss dynamic memory allocation pitfalls, techniques, good practices, etc. in C?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textbook [*Pointers On C*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0673999866) by Kenneth A. Reek (ISBN-13 978-0673999863) Chapter 11, Dynamic Memory is a decent teaching source. I don't know if it is available elsewhere at a better price.

The comprehensive reference would probable by [*C: A Reference Manual*](http://www.careferencemanual.com/), 5th ed by Samuel P. Harbison and Guy L. Steele (ISBN-13: 978-0130895929), covers C99 and although it is an excellent reference, not a straight teaching resource. I strongly recommend it for any serious C programmer's library.

Finally don't ignore the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) just because it has been around a while, it contains answers to the most commonly asked questions in Usenet's C language newsgroup (`comp.lang.c`) asked by thousands of students and new programmers. The only gotcha is that you need to read FAQ all the way through at least once, to know *where* (which sections) some questions are dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

[YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_type=search_videos&search_sort=relevance&search_query=dynamic+memory+allocation&search=Search).

Comment: thanks, yes, i watched them. too introductory. I'd like a bit more of a well-researched approach. Something like K&R would write. Take a look at the papers in the Wikipedia, they're good!